# How can I run Android applications on my PC with the Android emulator?

Tags: applications, android-emulator

Is it possible to run Android applications on PC (with emulator)? I have Android SDK on my PC and I want to run Angry Bird on it. Can any body help to me?

Comment: If the goal is just to play Angry Birds, then you can play it here: http://chrome.angrybirds.com/ It's a HTML5 version of Angry Birds, works like a charm.

Comment: I managed to install Google Play using this method, but when I restart the emulator everything is gone and I have to install again. Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 16):

I guess what you mean is to install applications from the market on the Android emulator. Well, normally this is not possible and also not suggested. The emulator is mainly intended for development purposes. The problem is also that you'd need to get the Android market in order to be able to download apps (Angry Birds in your case), but the emulator doesn't have the market app installed.

However, there is an interesting article by how-to-geek which describes how to install the Android market application on the emulator:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/

I didn't try it myself, but you may give it a try. Personally I think the overall user experience of playing Angry Birds on the emulator won't be great :)

Comment: would upvote for "Personally I think the overall user experience of playing Angry Birds on the emulator won't be great" alone. !!!

Answer (score 5):

Note that although Android OS itself is free (gratis and libre), Google's Android Market is not a free application (proprietary and device manufacturers have to pay license fee to Google if they want to legally include Market on their device); so installing Market on an emulator have a shady legality  (though I doubt Google would knock on your front door, you don't have enough money to be worth suing, and they wouldn't want to ruin their image of being open-friendly).

However, Angry Bird itself is free (gratis, not libre) application and there is no restriction on installing free application on an Android platform (e.g. emulator). As long as you can get the APK through other means than the Android Market (e.g. developer's site, etc), installing it on the emulator is fine. As it happens, GetJar is one of Rovio's official distribution channel, and you can Angry Bird from [there](http://www.getjar.com/mobile/43600/angry-birds/), note that you need to allow third party installation (Settings > Applications > tick "Unknown Sources", this is already ticked by default on the emulator).

Comment: i download .APK file but i dont know how to install it on emulator

Comment: @mahdi You just open it, there will be a prompt to install it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not particular about using SDK, then I would suggest using [BlueStacks](http://bluestacks.com/). It allows you to run android apps on your PC without the need for the Android SDK. It's a standalone installer and hence easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to install the application on your emulator you need the application's apk file.
Run (online) the emulator on which you want to install the application, then:

1. Copy the apk to `%PATH%\android-sdk\platform-tools`
2. Open a CMD prompt
3. Type `adb install application.apk`

This works for me but I don't know about gaming performance.

Note: whitespace characters are not allowed in application.apk file name. 
E.g.: `application name.apk` is not allowed, 
the file name must be like this `application_name.apk`.

Answer (score 0):

BlueStacks has an App Player that should do what you want.

> BlueStacks App Player lets you run apps from your phone fast and
>   fullscreen on Windows and Mac.

You can [download the beta free](http://www.bluestacks.com/).