# No Google Apps on Android Device Emulator

Tags: google, emulators

I have an Android Virtual Device set up on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but it doesn't seem to have any Google Apps when I start. The main purpose is to do some app testing and security analysis, but I need to install a few apps for that. The system doesn't permit any downloading too (I tried to download the apk) as any download attempt results in a browser crash. I tried the drag and drop method, to flash the gapps.zip file, but that didn't work. As of now, I have no Play Store from where I can install other apps. Please help. The device is a Nexus 5.

Comment: related  [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/how-can-i-run-android-applications-on-my-pc-with-the-android-emulator, though I'm a bit confused why you can't download APK from browser. You can install app using `adb install <filename.apk>` from your PC though.